# Possible to give fixed angle in path?

Tags: wpf, path, expression-blend

I have a path as shown in the attached image. i would like to know if it is possible to give a fixed angle for the edge of the path, coz i would like to use the same angle while styling other controls as well. Is there a way to make this possible (in Expression Blend)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using 'Subtract' Path Operation.

1) First draw the required shapes like

[image]

2) Draw a small rectangle and rotate it to a certain angle you want. Say 50. Then, place the small rotated rectangle over the shapes draw previously, like

[image]

3) Bring each of the Big Shapes to the front, like

[image]

4) Finally, goto "Object -> Combine -> Subtract" by selecting each big and small rectangle pair. The final output will have same angle, like

[image]

Comment: thanx for the answer, but my prob is still not solved as if the width of this path is increased, the length of the angle also increases. the angle remains the same i guess, but the length of that one side containing the angle increases. Is there anyway to sove this issue?